# Granger test: do I need stationarity?

Tags: stationarity, granger-causality

I have seen some people that granger test non-stationary time series; is in general allowed or does it apply only to specific cases?

Comment: See Dave Giles' famous blog post ["Testing for Granger causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.be/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) for the case of unit-root nonstationarity. Meanwhile, other types of nonstationarity are probably not covered there, but there is general knowledge that first-differencing nonintegrated time series yields integrated moving-average components and messes things up. This has been discussed in numerous older posts and can be looked up.

Comment: What do you think of my answer? You may ask for further clarification if something is still unclear. Otherwise, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left.

Answer (score 6):

*Some* types of nonstationarity are allowed, as long as we can build a model and a testing procedure that account for the specific type of nonstationarity. See Dave Giles' famous blog post ["Testing for Granger causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.be/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) for the case of unit-root nonstationarity.

But obviously, not *all* types of nonstationarity can be allowed for. If the time series is too erratic for any model we could manage to build, we will not have a way to carry out the test.